# Navigation Bar not showing with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, navbar

I have a project with the storyboard using auto Layout with the setting w any (size) y any (size). I embedded a navigation controller (with the first viewController). The first viewController has a navigation bar (as expected) but the second viewController doesn't. It has a top bar. I changed the color of the navigation controllers navBar, and they all change (as expected) but I cannot add a UIBarButton, or create a title for the second viewController.

(Please not that in my previous projects, when I didn't use auto layout, (I made it explicitly for the iphone,) all viewControllers had a nav bar.

Please don't be too harsh. I'm kinda new at this.

**Update**

Just realized it has top Layout guide, not top bar

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you saying it doesn't have a nav bar in the storyboard or when you run the app?

Comment: In the storyboard. It does show the top bar tho.

Comment: It doesn't show it in the outline layout either

Comment: How are you presenting the second view controller? If you create a Show segue in the storyboard from the first to second, it should show the nav bar.

Comment: do you mean show detail? I was using show

Comment: No, a Show segue should work. So you have nav controller -> first VC -> second VC ? That is correct. What does it look like when you run it? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: What do you mean Show segue. Where do you see that

Comment: When I run it on simulator, it has a back button???

Comment: When you embed a view controller in a navigation controller, you get a nav bar. When you segue to another view controller, it also has a nav bar. That's what it means to be in a navigation controller. Another behavior you get for free is the ability to navigate backwards via the Back button. Do a search for segues and you should find any number of tutorials that describe how to create one.

Comment: I have nav controller -> first VC -> second VC. On first VC, it has a nav bar at the top. On second vc it doesn't on the storyboard, but when I run it in simulator, it has a back button. What I want is the nav bar to show on second VC in the storyboard

Comment: How are you getting from first VC to second VC when you run the app? Are you tapping a button on the first VC, for example?

Comment: Yes I have a button segueing to second vc

Comment: Well, no idea why it's not showing in the storyboard, it should if you have the segue wired up correctly. Screenshot needed. Sorry I couldn't answer this.

Comment: Can you show the whole storyboard, especially where you say the nav bar is not showing?

Comment: Just updated question

Comment: Looks good. Your second VC has a nav bar. What is the issue?

Comment: I cannot add a title or ad a UIBarButton. If you look at the outline, (the first picture,) you will see there is no actual navbar

Comment: Try dragging a UIBarButtonItem to the nav bar of the second VC in the storyboard. If you look at your first VC, what you labeled the nav bar is actually a navigation item. The nav bar is defined in the navigation controller. You should be able to drag a UIBarButtonItem into your second VC in the storyboard (the taller of the two yellow bars).

Comment: When I do that, the button goes all the way to the bottom.